# PHP memory limit dont want to change

Tags: php

I'm trying to resize my memory limit by change the `php.ini`

[image]

But when I check using `phpinfo()` the result is this :

[image]

the memory limit still the same as default. I've restart MAMP and nothing changed.

I hope someone can help me to solve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the config in `phpinfo()`:

- `Configuration File (php.ini) Path => path`
- `Loaded Configuration File => path`

Is the path the same with the file you changed? Have you restart the apache?

Comment: Configuration File (php.ini) Path is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/conf ` 
Loaded Configuration File is `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.12/conf/php.ini `

what should I do ?

Comment: It seems the `php.ini` has not been loaded correctly. Is the picture in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/`? If so, try to create a dir named `conf` and copy the `php.ini` into the dir. It may work.

Comment: oooh, got it. I set the wrong `php.ini`. Thank you mate :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works:

Start MAMP PRO

Stop the server if it's running

Choose Menu -> File -> Edit Template -> PHP4 php.ini (If you want to change the memory limit for PHP5, then choose PHP5 php.ini)

The PHP ini file will be opened.

If a dialogue box pops up, read it and confirm with OK

Search (Command-F) for "memory_limit" (without quotes)

You should get the following line:

memory_limit = 8M ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8M)
Now you can change the default value of 8M. For instance. into 32M or even more (like 128M)

Save (Command-S) your changes.

Close (Command-W) the file.

Start the Server.

Credits : 
http://blog-en.mamp.info/2009/09/increase-php-memory-limit-with-mamp-pro.html

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're editing the wrong php.ini configuration file.

Check the **Loaded Configuration File** from `phpinfo()` output and make sure you're editing the correct php.ini configuration file.